# pyparsing using both OneOrMore and ZeroOrMore regardless of order

Tags: python-2.7, pyparsing

I am trying to get into pyparsing, I want to create what I think is a simple grammar for say a shopping basket. The following illustrates

- basket=['metal basket','wicker basket','plastic basket']
- fish=['haddock','plaice','dover sole']
- meat=['beef','lamb','pork']
- vegetable=['tomatoe','onion','cabbage','carrot']
- fruit=['apple','mango','orange','strawberry']

So the rule for shopping is you must have

- 1 Shopping basket
- 1 or more vegetables
- zero or more fruits
- fish are optional

The resulting parser must enforce the list of requirements above. It should not matter what order the items are placed in the basket, i.e a list
of

- metal basket
- haddock
- tomatoe
- apple
- cabbage
- orange

is just as valid as

- wicker basket
- tomatoe
- apple
- orange
- apple

The one that should fail however is
 - lamb
 - tomatoe
 - apple
 - wicker basket
 - apple

Because the basket must always be first in the list. I am at a loss as to how to do this
I have tired:

```
basket + OneOrMore(vegetable) + ZeroOrMore(fruit) + StringEnd()
```

But doesn't seem to work. I'm using pyparsing on python 2.7 on Windows 7. Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details about the actual strings you want to parse? Please give examples of strings which should succeed and strings which should not succeed parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Each` is the pyparsing class for specifying "all of these things, but in any order". Think of it as a special form of `And`. And in fact, the operator for `Each` is `&`.

You want to define various valid combinations of basket contents, after the basket is given first.

```
basket + (OneOrMore(vegetable) & ZeroOrMore(fruit) & ZeroOrMore(fish))
```

You can leave off the `StringEnd()` at the end - just specify `parseAll=True` in your call to `parseString`.

Alternatively, you could just put all the ingredients into a single clump like:

```
basket + ZeroOrMore(vegetable | fruit | fish)
```

and then put the validation into a parse action. I'm actually more in favor of this second approach than of using `Each` in the parser itself. For one thing, a parse action, implemented in Python code, can contain much more complex rules ("more vegetables than fruit", "at least as many vegetables as fish", "oysters only in months containing an 'R'", etc.). Also, I think these rules are more likely to change over time, and all such changes will be localized to the parse action, instead of forcing changes in the parser itself.